# Recursive relation to find a sequence $T_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I am working on defining an '$n$ digit' sequence $(T_n)$ where the string doesn't contain $99$: $929$ is okay but not $299$, and also $029$ is not okay as it will be considered a $2$-digit number and not $3$-digit (so it should basically not start with $0$).

So far I have got -

- $T_1 = 9$ cases (from $1$ to $9$)
- $T_2 = 9\times10 - \{99\} = 90 - 1 = 89$ cases
- $T_3 = 9\times 10\times 10 - \{99\}\times 10 - 9\times \{99\} = 900 - 10 - 9 = 881$ cases
- $T_4 =$ and here I mess up the cases that I can make

Of course the calculation for final number of outcomes is not necessary, but I am unable to understand how I can include/exclude cases for larger sequences :-(

Someone please help!

TIA!

Comment: Here's a tutorial of [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Your question will be better received in MSE if you show a little more effort writing them within the forum conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the title of your question talks about recursion, here is a recursive way of defining $T_n$:

Let $T_n^9$ be the number of $n$-digit numbers not containing $99$ and ending with $9$ and let $T_n^{\neg 9}$ be the number of $n$-digit numbers not containing $99$ and *not* ending with $9$.

Then we have the following recursive relations:

- $T_{n+1}^9 = T_n^{\neg 9}$ (an $n+1$ digit number ending with $9$ has to start with a $n$ digit number not ending with $9$ to avoid a $99$ at the end)
- $T_{n+1}^{\neg 9} = T_n \cdot 9$ (an $n+1$ digit number not ending with $9$ starts with any $n$ digit number (not containing $99$, of course) followed by one of the $9$ digits which are not $9$ (to avoid a $9$ at the end).

Of course, we also have $T_1^9 = 1$, $T_1^{\neg 9} = 8$ and $T_n = T_n^9 + T_n^{\neg 9}$.

As a sanity check:

| $n$ | $T_n^9$ | $T_n^{\neg 9}$ | $T_n$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8 | 1+8=9 |
| 2 | 8 | $9\cdot 9=81$ | 8+81=89 |
| 3 | 81 | $89\cdot 9 = 801$ | 81+801=882 |

which are exactly the numbers you got (including the correction by jjagmath)

---

**Edit:** And I just noticed that we can further simplyfy the recursion as follows:
$$T_{n+2} = T_{n+2}^9 + T_{n+2}^{\neg 9} = T_{n+1}^{\neg 9} + T_{n+1}\cdot 9 = T_n \cdot 9 + T_{n+1}\cdot 9 = 9\cdot(T_n + T_{n+1})$$
with initial terms $T_1 = 9$ and $T_2 = 89$.

**Edit2:** There is also a direct combinatorial argument of why the simpler recursion holds:

To get an $n+2$ digit number not containing a $99$ we can

- either take an $n+1$ digit number not containing a $99$ and add one of the digits $0,1,...,8$ at the end
- or take an $n$ digit number not containing a $99$ and add one of the digits $0,1,...,8$ followed by a $9$ at the end.

Now, it is easy to check that we really get all desired numbers this way and do not count any number twice :-)

Comment: To avoid a mutual recursion in the final answer, you may substitute to get $T_{n+2} = 9 T_{n+1}+ 9 T_n$ with initial terms $T_1 = 9$ and $T_2 = 89$.

Comment: Good point! Had the same idea at the same time :-)
And good idea to also add the two initial terms. I will also do that.